# Why does ubuntu end up with different versions of python and pip and django gets installed globally instead of in the virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to learn Django and I installed ubuntu bash on Windows to use it there. As ubuntu comes with Python preinstalled but not pip, I installed pip and updated it. However, when I use `pip3 -V` it shows the past version of pip. There are two pip installs and I can't figure out how to upgrade the one that Python uses. I also installed Django when I was already inside the virtualenv but it was installed globally, so I guess this is because of the same problem.

Does anyone know how can I have just one python and one pip installed to avoid those issues? I reinstalled ubuntu because I got really annoyed...

Comment: Can you add the exact steps/commands to reproduce the issue? Running `which pip3` will give you the location of the  `pip3` executable you will run and should let you know if you are running the correct one when in the venv

Comment: Read this, it might help: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

Addiing venv to path is not the correct way to work in a venv you have to source bin/activate and use pip not pip3 since there the correct pip is loaded automatically. Ides source venv automatically when opened in the project directory. This allows to have a clean environment for each project

Answer (score -1):

I already solved it, adding to PATH the path of the other pip, thanks to the guys who answered.